# Inviting/Removing Workspace Users with an App/Bot on Slack Enterprise Grid

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm working on a Slack integration for our workspace that is within an Enterprise Grid. I have a workspace and I've created a Slack App with all possible OAuth scopes and have installed it in the workspace.

I'd like to automatically invite and remove users to our workspace using the app/bot. I should be able to do this with the Slack app/bot using the [admin.users.invite](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.invite) and [admin.users.remove](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.remove) API actions.

However, these two actions require the [admin.users:write OAuth scope](https://api.slack.com/scopes/admin.users:write), which can only be used on an App that is installed organization-wide, so I can't use this scope on my workspace app:

> The app requesting this scope must be installed by an admin or Owner of an Enterprise Grid organization. Also, the app must be installed on the entire org, not on an individual workspace.

Is there any other way I can have an automated system that invites/removes users to/from our workspace, without it being an organization-wide app? This is something I can do as a user through the Slack UI (and I'm not an organization admin, just a workspace admin), so one would think I should be able to do the same things via an app/bot that is installed and authorized to act on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the APIs currently provided by Slack are available for **Org Owner & Org Admin** roles.

The best course of action for you will be to collaborate with your org admins. 
 Let them manage the app. It means you will not have access to token, but you can use the app as a user.

1. Create the app that will operate only on your workspace by using fixed teamId.
2. Ask the org admin to generate the `admin` token and update that in your app.

May be, if they find your app useful, it can be used across organization eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can you tell me a bit more about how to "use the app as a user"? i.e. if there's a an app installed organization-wide, how would I, as a user, use it programmatically?

Comment: There will be two apps. One will be with admin scope to be installed org wide. You can create another app with required functionality and provide token generated from first app to call required apis.

Comment: The admins will generate org wide token & add the generated token to the second app (may be as environment variable)